# Workbox with Angular 12 Error: Can't find self.__WB_MANIFEST in your SW source

Tags: angular, service-worker, workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin

I'm getting a weird error when I trying out workbox and angular.

Have been following the guide and docs at workbox and have also search for the answer but cant find any solution that fits for me.

Anyway, I get this error

> Error: Can't find self.__WB_MANIFEST in your SW source.

when I create a `service-worker.js` with this code

**service-worker.js**

```
import { precacheAndRoute } from "workbox-precaching";
import { registerRoute } from "workbox-routing";
import { StaleWhileRevalidate } from "workbox-strategies";
import { BroadcastUpdatePlugin } from "workbox-broadcast-update";

// Use with precache injection
precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST);

registerRoute(
  ({ url }) => url.pathname.startsWith("/"),
  new StaleWhileRevalidate({
    plugins: [new BroadcastUpdatePlugin()],
  })
);
```

But if I comment out the import of `StaleWhileRevalidate` it works.

```
import { precacheAndRoute } from "workbox-precaching";
import { registerRoute } from "workbox-routing";
// import { StaleWhileRevalidate } from "workbox-strategies";
import { BroadcastUpdatePlugin } from "workbox-broadcast-update";

// Use with precache injection
precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST);

registerRoute(
  ({ url }) => url.pathname.startsWith("/"),
  new StaleWhileRevalidate({
    plugins: [new BroadcastUpdatePlugin()],
  })
);
```

Do anyone have a clue why this is happening?

I'm going for the `inject manifest` approach.

**webpack.config.js**

```
const { InjectManifest } = require("workbox-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  // Other webpack config...
  plugins: [
    // Other plugins...
    new InjectManifest({
      swSrc: "./src/service-worker.js",
    }),
  ],
};
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "angular-main",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~12.2.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "workbox-precaching": "^6.3.0",
    "workbox-window": "^6.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^12.1.2",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.2.5",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.8.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "^6.3.0"
  }
}
```

**angular.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "angular-main": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        },
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/angular-main",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "customWebpackConfig": {"path": "./webpack.config.js"},
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "angular-main:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "angular-main:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "angular-main:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "angular-main"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it, it seams that the version diff between `@angular-builders/custom-webpack` and `@angular-devkit/build-angular` broke the build. Maybe it will help someone else.

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^12.1.2",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.2.5",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.1.2",
    ...
```